# pass values from javascript function to php file is not working for me

Tags: javascript, php, xml

i want to send two variables values from one file, which have XML code where i have function which include the php file, so i want it should include this php file with my passed values, am doing like following way

---

```
function load(){
    var id=cn;
    var name="zuni";

    downloadUrl('info.php?id2=id&name2=name', function(data) {

    });
```

---

> code in info.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id2 = $_GET['id2'];
    $name2 = $_GET['name2']; 
    echo "id is :". $id2;
    echo "name is :". $name2; 
}
```

---

its output is showing like this

---

```
id is:id
name is: name
```

its not displaying variable value but variable name, i want its value not name any one can check whats wrong with this code ?

Comment: What? In `id2=id&name2=name` value of `id2` is `id`, same to `name2`. And scripts outputs just what you've passed to it.

Comment: @u_mulder i want to to pass value of name2="zuni" not name2=name

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the request URL that you are passing have literal values

```
  'info.php?id2=id&name2=name'.
```

To solve the problem you have to use the code below instead:

```
  "info.php?id2=" + id + "&name2=" + name
```

Comment: @mjunaid It is always my pleasure to give back to the community ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you want your code to work you shoud use back tick to inject your variable in your download request :

```
downloadUrl(`info.php?id2=${id}&name2=${name}`, function(data) {
```

or use the string concatenation

```
downloadUrl('info.php?id2=' + id + '&name2=' + name, function(data) {
```

you actually pass id and name to your GET resquest. This is normal that your server get `id` and `name`.